# why can i assign a raw string value but not a variable?

Tags: c++

I followed a tutorial on youtube to develop a program in c++ to send a short message over a serialport and listen for a response. I am using the Serialport library(not the default c++ one, an external one) (https://github.com/greiman/SerialPort/blob/master/SerialPort/SerialPort.h). The program in the video uses the port 10 to communicate, but I want the user to be able to enter a specific port which the program then uses to communicate. But i'm struggling with the assignment of a variable. The library has a class called Serialport, that takes a char pointer as a parameter like so:

```
char* port;
SerialPort arduino(port);
```

The guy in the video then gives the char pointer the value of a String, like so:

```
char* port = "\\\\.\\COM10";
```

and then the code works flawlessly. Which I find odd for several reasons.

First of all, "port" is a pointer, so shoulnd't it be pointing to some other value? like so:

```
char port1 = 'a';
char* port2 = port1;
```

second of all, why does he use a char pointer to point to a string? and why does that work?

i've tried using a variable instead of assigning the value to the pointer directly, so that the user can enter the port they want to use, like so:

```
string portone;
cout << "specify port: " << endl;
cin >> portone;
string porttwo = "\\\\.\\COM" + portone;
port = porttwo;
```

But then vs studio tells me "there is no suitable conversion function from string to char".

so, in conclusion i'm asking:

why does this:

```
char* port = "\\\\.\\COM10";
```

work, but this:

```
string portone = "\\\\.\\COM10";
char* porttwo = portone;
```

does not.

And is there any way to assign a variable value to the char pointer to let the user specify the port?

my entire code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
#include"SerialPort.h"

char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
char incomingData[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
// change the name of the port with the port name of your computer
// must remember that the backslashes are essential so do not remove them
char* port;

int main() {
    string data;
    string portone;
    cout << "Escribi el port: " << endl;
    cin >> portone;
    string porttwo = "\\\\.\\COM" + portone;
    port = porttwo;
    SerialPort arduino(port);
    if (arduino.isConnected()) {
        cout << "Conectado" << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Puerto 10 vacio" << endl << endl;
    }
    if (arduino.isConnected()) {
        cout << "Escribi el string: " << endl;
        cin >> data;
        char* charArray = new char[data.size() + 1];
        copy(data.begin(), data.end(), charArray);
        charArray[data.size()] = '\n';
        arduino.writeSerialPort(charArray, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
        arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

        cout << "Respuesta: " << output << endl;

        delete[] charArray;
    }
    cout << "Terminado" << endl << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

serialport class:

```
#include "SerialPort.h"

SerialPort::SerialPort(char *portName)
{
    this->connected = false;

    this->handler = CreateFileA(static_cast<LPCSTR>(portName),
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    if (this->handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available\n", portName);
        }
    else
        {
            printf("ERROR!!!");
        }
    }
    else {
        DCB dcbSerialParameters = {0};

        if (!GetCommState(this->handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters");
        }
        else {
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

            if (!SetCommState(handler, &dcbSerialParameters))
            {
                printf("ALERT: could not set Serial port parameters\n");
            }
            else {
                this->connected = true;
                PurgeComm(this->handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    if (this->connected){
        this->connected = false;
        CloseHandle(this->handler);
    }
}

int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    unsigned int toRead = 0;

    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0){
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size){
            toRead = buf_size;
        }
        else toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
    }

    if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) return bytesRead;

    return 0;
}

bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    if (!WriteFile(this->handler, (void*) buffer, buf_size, &bytesSend, 0)){
        ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return this->connected;
}
```

links:

youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BWjyZxGr5o

serialport.h: https://github.com/greiman/SerialPort/blob/master/SerialPort/SerialPort.h

Comment: A string literal has the type `const char[]` - that's how it is defined in the C++ standard. Any kind of `string` (such as `std::string`) is a class, defined in some library. You can get a `const char*` from your `std::string` via the `c_str()` member function

Comment: And as far as your question if a pointer "shoulnd't it be pointing to some other value" you should find a discussion of how arrays become pointers, like a character arrays that represents string literals, in your C++ textbook; and everything should be crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char* port = "\\\\.\\COM10";
> ```
>
> and then the code works flawlessly. Which I find odd for several reasons.
>
> First of all, "port" is a pointer, so shoulnd't it be pointing to some other value? like so:
>
> ```
> char port1 = 'a';
> char* port2 = port1;
> ```

```
char *port = "whatever";
```

*is* creating a variable (named `port`) that points at a value (the characters you put inside the quotes). It's basically telling the compiler to store the string you specified *somewhere* in memory (but we don't care much exactly where), then create a variable (named `port`, in this case) holding its address.

As far as your second example goes, yes, you could create a pointer referring to the value in some other variable, *but* you need one minor change. A pointer holds an address, so you need to take the address of that variable, so your example would work more like this:

```
char port1 = 'a';
char *port2 = &port1;
```

Note, however, that the name of an *array* normally evaluates to the address of the beginning of the array, so in this case we *don't* need to use the address-of operator (we just get the address by default):

```
static char portCharacters[] = "\\\\.\\COM10";
char *port1 = portCharacters;
```

This is almost the same as the first example you gave. The minor difference is that in this case we've given a name directly to the storage where the characters are stored, and also to a pointer to that location.

A couple other points worth noting here:

- in C it's pretty routine to assume that a `char *` will point at a NUL-terminated string. That is, that it'll point to the beginning of an array of characters with a '\0' byte signalling the end of the array. That's not necessarily the case with the `char *port1 = &port2;` case, so we have to be kind of careful with it, to assure against accidentally trying to use it like a string, when it's really only referring to a single character.
- In current C++, you can't actually do `char *a = "foo";`. You need to use `char const *a = "foo";` (or, equivalently) `const char *a = "foo";`. This doesn't really change anything materially--trying to modify a string literal gives undefined behavior, and will often fail (e.g., get your program killed). But by requiring the `const` there, a modern compiler will enforce this by stopping your code from compiling if you try to modify a string literal (though if you insist, you can bypass that).